# Add web image to pdf

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to add a web image to a pdf using iTextSharp

I am attempting to use the same code that you would use for a local image

```
using (var pdfDoc = new Document()) 
using (var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, pdfStream)) { 
    pdfDoc.Open();
    Image tif = Image.GetInstance("www.myimage.com");
    pdfDoc.Add(tif);
    pdfDoc.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to the other posted answer, you do **NOT** need to make a separate HTTP request. Just make sure you use [an absolute URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier#Examples_of_absolute_URIs) when calling `Image.GetInstance()`:

```
string url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Pollinationn.jpg/320px-Pollinationn.jpg";
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
  document.Open();
  Image img = Image.GetInstance(url);
  document.Add(img);
}
```

This is [clearly documented for the overloaded method call](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#getInstance-java.net.URL-).

Answer (score 5):

You have to make a http web request to download the image first.

```
public Image DownloadImageFromURL(string url)
{
   HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(filename);
   httpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;            
   httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";            
   httpWebRequest.Timeout = 30000; //30 seconds
   webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();    
   webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
   Image downloadImage = Image.FromStream(webStream);            
   webResponse.Close();   
   return downloadImage;
}

//in your code
    using (var pdfDoc = new Document()) 
using (var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, pdfStream)) { 
    pdfDoc.Open();
    Image tif = DownloadImageFromURL("www.myimage.com");
    pdfDoc.Add(tif);
    pdfDoc.Close();
}
```

Use this method to make a HttpWebRequest and download the image. Now write it in to pdf now.